# Re-render visual-force panel twice in single button click

Tags: visualforce, rerender

On my `Visualforce Page`, there are **two chained long running call outs** when users click a button. I'd like to know if I can re-render a panel twice in that click. So that the results can be displayed as soon as it comes back. Currently the panel only re-renders once after calling `processChainedResponse()`.

I looked at this example: [Chaining Asynchronous Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_chained_callouts.htm).

Note: you may need to put `https://node-count.herokuapp.com/` under your `Remote Site Settings` to reproduce.

### What I'd like to achieve/know:

Can I re-render when the page executes the method `processInitialResponse()`
and also when it executes `processChainedResponse()`?

### Example code

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="ContinuationController" showChat="false" showHeader="false">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!invokeInitialRequest}" value="Start Request" reRender="panel"/>  
   </apex:form>
   <apex:outputPanel id="panel"> 
       <apex:outputText value="{!result1}" />
       <br/>
       <apex:outputText value="{!result2}" />
   </apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class ContinuationController {
    public String requestLabel1;
   
    public String requestLabel2;

    public String result1 {get;set;}
  
    public String result2 {get;set;}

    private static final String LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL1 = 'https://node-count.herokuapp.com/5';
    private static final String LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL2 = 'https://node-count.herokuapp.com/10';
           

    public Object invokeInitialRequest() {
     
      Continuation con = new Continuation(60);

      con.continuationMethod='processInitialResponse';
      
      // Create first callout request
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setEndpoint(LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL1);
      
      this.requestLabel1 = con.addHttpRequest(req);              
      
      return con;  
    }
    
    // Callback method for initial request
    // Re-render 
    public Object processInitialResponse() {   
      HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(this.requestLabel1);

      this.result1 = response.getBody();  
      Continuation chainedContinuation = null;
     
      if (response.getBody().toLowerCase().contains('5')) {
          // Create a second continuation 
          chainedContinuation = new Continuation(60);
          // Set callback method
          chainedContinuation.continuationMethod='processChainedResponse';
          
          HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
          req.setMethod('GET');
          req.setEndpoint(LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL2);
    
          this.requestLabel2 = chainedContinuation.addHttpRequest(req); 
      }
      
      // Start another continuation 
      return chainedContinuation;  
    }    
    
    // Callback method for chained request
    // Re-render again
    public Object processChainedResponse() {   
      // Get the response for the chained request
      HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(this.requestLabel2);
      // Set the result variable that is displayed on the Visualforce page
      this.result2 = response.getBody();
           
      // Return null to re-render the original Visualforce page
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could chain them on the client side rather than in the controller. I.e. Let the first continuation return and re-render the panel. Then us something like the oncomplete attribute to start the second continuation.